# Eclipse Debug issue

Tags: eclipse, selenium, remote-debugging

Please help in understanding and resolving this issue which appears while debugging in Eclipse. Earlier, when i used to debug I never had this issue. And to verify whether its like that only, i also checked in other computer but it does not appear over there. Usually, in debug mode, debugger would stop at the debug line but once i press continue F8(resume button) then it gets there.

[image: Screenshot]

Note: The PC is in office network and no internet access. I am assuming the issue may also be caused by one of the action i had taken.There was "Add Source" issue for a jar file and i had added the same jar as source file. May be this may have caused it?? Please suggest.

Comment: `attributes` is `null` here and so `attributes.entrySet()` causes the NPE. Could you please be more specific about what is unclear to you here? Maybe you're just confused that it happens over and over again, so _Resume_ doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: I'm saying when I debug other program in other PCs, I don't encounter this step and earlier also I never used to have this in this existing PC. Resume moves on to the debug point which is fine and after that no issues..so I'm asking why is it coming in during the debug mode now? How to fix? Exactly, how do I fix this NPE?

Comment: Issue resolved..I had it on breakpoins..removed and resolved

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved..I had it on breakpoints..removed and resolved